# Delete All Columns At Right Of Last Non Empty Column

Tags: excel, vba

as subject suggests I am looking a simple VBA line to delete all columns at right of the last non empty column.

I already have a simple code for deleting all rows below last non empty row like this:

```
Rows(Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row + 1 & ":" & Rows.Count).Delete
```

I am looking for the same simple single line code to use with columns but I am struggling to find it.

Any help will be apprecieted thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe:

```vb
Dim colNumber as Integer
colNumber = Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column +1
Range(Cells(1, colNumber), Cells(1, 16384)).EntireColumn.Delete
```

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Range(Cells(1,Columns.Count).End(xltoleft).Offset(0,1),cells(1,columns.Count)).entirecolumn.delete
```